# GLFW in docker container through ssh

Tags: c++, docker, ubuntu, ssh, glfw

I'm trying to resurrect some old code, which relies on script with GLFW.

Source code for script can be viewed [here](https://github.com/adobe-research/MakeItTalk/blob/6518811f2081fe5260e9b919e201ef6b2eed58dd/facewarp/facewarp/src/facewarp.cpp)

The problem is, I need to run it inside the nvidia docker container (nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:21.06-py3), which is deployed on the server without any Display connected to it. The only way to access server, as usual, is ssh connection.

When calling the script I keep having the same exception:
`EXCEPTION: GLFW initialization failed.`, which is the result of

```cpp
 if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE) { 
    throw std::runtime_error("GLFW initialization failed."); 
}
```

calling `glfwGetError(&description)` results in

```bash
X11: Failed to open display unix:0
```

The problem is - there is no default value for $DISPLAY on the server.

I've tried to manually set it on host machine via `export DISPLAY=:0`, and then share host x11 socket with running container:

```bash
docker run --gpus all -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY -it --rm --shm-size 1G  \
        -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.x11-unix \
        <image>
```

after connecting to the server with x11 forwarding (`ssh -X bla@bla`)

But it didn't solve the problem

So my question basically is - how can I make it work? Should I recompile GLFW with some special options, so it will be able to work without set $DISPLAY. Or maybe there is way to invoke mock display in docker container ?

I really need this script to work independently i.e. without any active ssh connections and hence without any x11 forwarding

Comment: If there is no display connected then I doubt that OpenGL will work.  You might make more progress switching to Vulkan (non-trivial, I know) which can work in headless mode.

Comment: see https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/648, https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1592 and https://github.com/glfw/glfw/pull/1608

Answer (score 0):

I added `#include <stdexcept>` to `facewarp.cpp`.

> Or maybe there is way to invoke mock display in docker container?

Yes there is: use a framebuffer (`xvfb`) to emulate X11.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:21.06-py3

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -y -qq \
        g++ \
        libglfw3-dev \
        libstb-dev \
        xvfb

COPY facewarp.cpp .
RUN g++ -I/usr/include/stb/ facewarp.cpp -lGL -lglfw -o facewarp

ENV DISPLAY=:99

ENTRYPOINT []
CMD Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16 & ./facewarp
```

[image]